# How to mock an argument that returns a new class in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, arguments, phpunit

I'm having a problem with a line of code like:

```
$user->has('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'unverified')))
```

I can mock the first argument, but can only assert that the 2nd argument returns a class. In some classes I make multiple uses of `has` and need to be able to test them properly. To be clear, I need to confirm that "unverified" was passed into the factory method of the 2nd argument. Any help is much appreciated.

The class I'm testing:

```
<?php
/**
 * Policy class to determine if a user can upload a file.
 */
class Policy_File_Upload extends Policy
{
    const NOT_LOGGED_IN = 1;
    const NOT_VERIFIED = 2;

    public function execute(Model_ACL_User $user, array $extra = NULL)
    {
        if ($user->can('login'))
        {
            return self::NOT_LOGGED_IN;
        }
        elseif ($user->has('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'unverified'))))
        {
            return self::NOT_VERIFIED;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

and the corresponding test:

```
public function test_guest()
{
    // User mock
    $user = $this->getMock('Model_User', array('can', 'has'), array(), '', FALSE);
    $user->expects($this->any())->method('can')->with('login')->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));
    $user->expects($this->any())->method('has')->with('roles', $this->logicalOr
    (

    ))
    ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'roles')));


    $policy = new Policy_File_Upload;

    $this->assertSame(Policy_File_Upload::NOT_VERIFIED, $policy->execute($user));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To be clear, I need to confirm that "unverified" was passed into the factory method of the 2nd argument.

```
<?php

public function execute(Model_ACL_User $user, array $extra = NULL)
    [...] ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'unverified')) [...]
```

I'm sorry mate, you can't do that as there is no (sane) way to mock out a static method call.

The argument to why this is a problem are similar to one of Sebastian Bergmanns blog post: [`Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons`](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html)

There are options like [`runkit`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) that you could choose to replace the "ORM" class at runtime with a mocked version but thats really painfull.

### So there are a couple of options:

You could create something like a **`Policy_File_Upload_Data_Provider`** that has a **`->getRoles`** method where you put your ORM access. That would allow you to test your business logic nicely and testing that data access class should be a little easier as it doesn't to that much (just accessing the orm).

You could Inject your ORM class (or if that doesn't work out maybe just its name). 
Depending on the class its self you should be able to create an instance and call ->factory like it would be a normal method. You could mock that.

If you don't want that just leaving that in there is also a not SO bad option.

Hope that at least gave you an idea/overview.

---

Additional Links why it's hard to test statics:

[**`Misko Hevery - Flaw: Brittle Global State & Singletons`**](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/)

[**`Kore Nordmann - Static considered harmful`**](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can always go the data-driven route of preparing test data for each case and verify the result of calling the function. In the end, you don't so much care that `'unverified'` gets passed to `ORM::factory()` but rather that the correct result comes out of `execute()` based on the input.

Testing the implementation details makes the test brittle and difficult to write. If you can test the results instead, your tests won't break when you change how you arrive at the result. It may take longer to put together a data set for all your use cases, but it can generally be shared among tests.

Comment: Sure, but I need a way to pass in data to the function to make sure the logic works. So with your advice I can set an array of roles a user should have and assert the correct result.

Comment: Yes, to test the `NOT_VERIFIED` case you would pass in a user that has the single role `'unverified'`. If `ORM::factory()` is broken, this test will erroneously be reported as broken as well, but the `ORM` tests should clue you in to the real problem. I use a mixture of all these techniques depending on the situation, but I favor data-driven tests since they are more strictly results oriented.

Comment: I misunderstood you with my first comment, apologies. I see you're saying I need to create data sets to test against. I will look into this too.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do verification on parameters passed to mock methods utilizing [parameter capturing](http://phake.digitalsandwich.com/docs/html/ch05s03.html)  in the [Phake mocking framework](http://github.com/mlively/Phake) for PHP.

```
public function test_guest()
{
    // User mock
    $user = Phake::mock('Model_User');
    when($user)->can('login')->thenReturn(FALSE);
    when($user)->has('roles', $this->anything())->thenGetReturnByLambda(array($this, 'roles'));

    $policy = new Policy_File_Upload;

    $this->assertSame(Policy_File_Upload::NOT_VERIFIED, $policy->execute($user));

    Phake::verify($user)->has('roles', Phake::capture($factoriedRole));

    $this->assertEquals('unverified', $factoriedRole->get('name'));
}
```

This example is assuming that you have the ability to check the name on $factoriedRole, obviously that piece needs to be changed depending on how that ORM stack works.

A small note, I agree with edorian regarding statics. If possible I would always prefer redesigning your code to not require statics, but sometimes that isn't possible, in which case this is a workable solution.

[Phake Github Page](http://github.com/mlively/Phake)

[Phake Documentation on Parameter Capturing](http://phake.digitalsandwich.com/docs/html/ch05s03.html)